# Check if apps have been transferred in iPad backup to iTunes

Tags: ios, itunes, ipad, backup

I just backed up my iPad 1st Gen into iTunes on my MacBook Pro, but I need to make sure all my apps have been transferred. How can I check this?

Answer (score 1):

You could use an app such as [**iPhone / iPod Touch Backup Extractor**](http://supercrazyawesome.com) (for Mac) and [**iPhone Backup Extractor**](http://www.iphonebackupextractor.com) (for Windows) to check the backup to make sure that the files that you require have been successfully backed up.

If necessary, you could attempt to restore the files to be certain that you have access to them.